# ordering of multiple jndi.properties on classpath

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

I have a jboss web service that is getting the wrong initial context.  I want it to use the `java.naming.factory.initial` from the `jndi.properties` in the services root directory and not the one in jboss `jndi.properties` which is the `NamingContextFactory`.  In the ant build file I put the `jndi.properties` in the classpath and made sure it copies over to the archive, but the service still gets the `NamingContextFactory` instead.  How can I tell which `jndi.properties` gets used so that the factory gets set correctly?

The unfortunate situation is that I have a third party jar I must use that expects its initial context factory to be the one specified in its packaged `jndi.properties` file, but when I run this in jboss it gets `NamingContextFactory`. I can't change the jboss `jndi.properties` file without everything breaking.

Comment: You might have to perform some JBoss classloading gymnastics. Is the JAR part of an EAR or a WAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple `jndi.properties` files in the root of the classpath, then `InitialContext` will make some attempt to merge the two, but which one wins is more or less a matter of chance.

If you want to make sure, then `InitialContext` has a constructor that takes a `Hashtable` of properties, where you can specify them explicitly. That would be preferable to implicit loading via `jndi.properties`, in this case. You can always load your target `jndi.properties` into a `Properties` object (which is a subclass of `Hashtable`), and pass that to the constructor.

Comment: Edited my post to include that I don't control the initial context request a third party library does... :(